# Calculating Symmetrie Groups of Differential Equations from the Infinitesimal Generators (Vectorfields)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields

At the moment I am working through the Book "Applications of Lie-Groups to Differential-Equations" by Peter Olver.

On page 120 he calculates the symmetrie groups of the heat equation.
$$ u_{t} = u_{xx} \quad \text{with} \quad u = f(x,t), $$

with the notation

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u_x $$

He finds the infinitesimal generators of the symmetrie groups of the differential equation and then procceds to calculate the group action of the symmetrie groups. He finds 7 vectorfields (the infinitesimal generators) which are the basis of the Lie-Algebra of a local group of transformations (which is a Lie-Group). For example he finds

$$ v_1 = \partial_x $$

and the symmetrie group is

$$ G_1: (x,t,u) \rightarrow (\tilde{x},\tilde{t},\tilde{u}) = (x + \varepsilon,t,u).  $$

This caluclation is clear for me, as he just solves the differential equation

$$ \frac{dx}{d\varepsilon} = 1,  $$

which, as I understand it, is finding the flow generated by the vectorfield and that the flow is equal to a one-parameter group of transformations.

But then he proceeds to calculate the symmetrie groups of the vector fields

$$ v_2 = 2t\partial_x -xu\partial_u\\ 
   v_3 = 4tx\partial_x +4t^2\partial_t - (x^2+2t)u\partial_u$$

which are given by

$$ G_2: \Bigl(x + 2t\varepsilon,t,u \cdot exp(-\varepsilon x - \varepsilon^2 t)\Bigr),\\
   G_3: \Bigl(\frac{x}{1-\varepsilon t},\frac{t}{1-\varepsilon t}, u \cdot \sqrt{1-4\varepsilon t} \cdot exp\{\frac{-\varepsilon x^2}{1-4\varepsilon t}\} \Bigr). $$

I dont seem to understand how he calculated these group actions, especially the action on u.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For the first, you have $\dot x = 2t$, $\dot t = 0$, $\dot u = -xu$. So you get (separating variables for the last one): $x(\epsilon) = x+2t\epsilon$, $t(\epsilon)=t$, $\log u(\epsilon) - \log u = -(x\epsilon + t\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the hint I needed to understand the first two calculations. But I am still struggling to calculate the action of the symmetrie group for the last vectorfield. I dont know where to "start" (for lack of a better word) because f.e. I cannot solve for $$ r(\varepsilon) $$ and then use this to solve $$ t(\varepsilon) $$   because of the t dependence in $$ 2rt\partial_r $$. A hint would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No, you have to work with $r,t$ together. I would suggest getting an implicit relation between $r$ and $t$ by eliminating the $\epsilon$ parameter. Note that $\dot r = 2rt$, $\dot t = r^2+t^2$ leads to a homogeneous ODE $dt/dr$.

Comment: Please do not delete a question after someone has given you an answer, whether it be in a comment or in an answer.